# pandas split all list column and get first value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get first element in the list for all rows and column into a single dataframe. All of the rows and columns have list format. It contains 2 elements in each list. Here is what I tried. What syntax should I use to apply entire dataframe in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def my_function(x):
    return x.replace('\[','').replace('\]','').split(',')[0]

t = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ['[blah,blah]','[test,bing]',np.NaN], 'col2': ['[math,sci]',np.NaN,['number','4']]})
print(t)
```

not working:

```
t.apply(my_function) # AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
t.apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('\[','').replace('\]','').split(',')[0]) # does not work
t.apply(lambda x: list(x)[0]) # gives first column and doesn't split
```

trying to get this:

```
col1  col2
blah  math
test  NaN
NaN  number
```

Comment: Is the last element `['number','4']` an actual list or also a string in list format ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`:

```
>>> t.replace(r'\[([^,]*).*', r'\1', regex=True)
   col1    col2
0  blah    math
1  test     NaN
2   NaN  number
```

But I think you have an error when you create your sample dataframe. I changed to:

```
t = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ['[blah,blah]','[test,bing]',np.NaN],
                       'col2': ['[math,sci]',np.NaN,'[number,4]']})
# The problem is here ------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Link to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/b9pv9T/1)